# How to compare Unicode characters in SQL server?

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005, unicode, ascii

Hi I am trying to find all rows in my database (SQL Server) which have character **é** in their text by executing the following queries.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_question WHERE patindex(N'%[\xE9]%',question) > 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_question WHERE patindex(N'%[\u00E9]%',question) > 0;
```

But I found two problems: (a) Both of them are returning different number of rows and (b) They are returning rows which do not have the specified character.

Is the way I am constructing the regular expression and comparing the Unicode correct?

EDIT:

The question column is stored using datatype `nvarchar`.
The following query gives the correct result though.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_question WHERE question LIKE N'%é%';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_question WHERE question LIKE N'%é%'`?

NB: `Like`and `patindex` do **not** accept regular expressions.

In the SQL Server pattern syntax `[\xE9]` means [match any single character within the specified set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489%28SQL.90%29.aspx). i.e. match `\`, `x`, `E` or `9`. So any of the following strings would match that pattern.

- "Elephant"
- "axis"
- "99.9"

Comment: So the first one is matching with \,0,0,E or 9? Is there a way to actually specify the unicode in the query?

Comment: @Ravi - You could use `WHERE patindex(N'%' + NCHAR(0xE9) + '%',question) > 0` if for some reason you don't want to just use the literal `WHERE patindex(N'%é%',question) > 0`

Comment: Thanks a bunch Martin. This really helped. I was under the impression that PATINDEX supports the normal regular expressions.