# Using unicode blocks in MSSQL regex queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, unicode

What I need is to select all records containing characters from Unicode blocks. For example, next regex matches string that consists only from characters of [Basic Latin](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/basic-latin/) unicode block:

```
^[\u0000-\u007F]+$
```

How unicode blocks could be used in sql queries?

Comment: Seems like a Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319546/how-to-compare-unicode-characters-in-sql-server
Also you can use the `Like` operator with the given unicode symbol: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx#Anchor_5